# Fastest way to detect degeneracy in a matrix

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, linear-programming, linear-independence

Given that degeneracy in a matrix seems to be 3 or more lines/vectors intersecting the same point (assumption), I am wondering about the fastest algorithm that can detect degeneracy in a matrix. Say we have:

```
[
  [ a, b, c, d, e, f],
  [ g, h, i, j, k, l],
  [ m, n, o, p, q, r]
]
```

I suppose the matrix is degenerate if these three vectors intersect? but to determine if they intersect, I think we need to have b-values, let's tack those on:

```
[
  [ a, b, c, d, e, f, = b1],
  [ g, h, i, j, k, l, = b2],
  [ m, n, o, p, q, r, = b3]
]
```

how can we go about doing this for a matrix of MxN?

At this time, I don't know if a degenerate point for vectors with N dimensions needs to intersect at the same point for *all* (in this case N) dimensions or just 2+...N makes more sense to me.

My best guess is that a degenerate point occurs under these conditions:

1. *3 or more vectors (vectors with dimension N)*
2. *intersecting at the same point in all N dimensions*

but if that's not correct, please correct me. Note that degeneracy in a linear system might pertain specifically to linear optimization methods, here is some background:

[http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/ieor3608.F05/degeneracy1.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ecs2035/courses/ieor3608.F05/degeneracy1.pdf)

https://advol.cas.mcmaster.ca/feng/4O03/LP.Degeneracy.pdf

Comment: if someone could add the `degeneracy` tag that'd be greatt

Comment: What do you mean by "degenerate"? Neither possible definition I'm aware of (determinant zero or having eigenvalues with multiplicity greater than $1$) applies to matrices that aren't square.

Comment: Perhaps it only applies to square matrices - not sure - but it's a term used in Linear Optimization (Linear Programming using Simplex algorithm)

Comment: http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/ieor3608.F05/degeneracy1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In Linear Programming, the quickest way to denote a degenerate Linear Model is when the Minimum Ratio Test is the same for two or more rows on the same basis. This ensures that the other row that is not chosen will have a zero right-hand-side that will forever not contribute to the model upon future pivots.

An example (with $x_1$ being the pivot column):

\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & RHS & RT \\ \hline
z & 1 & -1 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 &0 &0& - \\ \hline
s_1 & 0 & 2 & -4 &1 & 0 &0& 8 & 4 \\ \hline
s_2 & 0 & 2 & 1&0& 1 &0& 8 & 4 \\ \hline
s_3 & 0 & -7 & 25&0 & 0 &1&29 & \infty \\ \hline
\end{array}

then,
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & RHS & RT \\ \hline
z & 1 & 0 & -15 & 0 & 0 &0 &40& - \\ \hline
x_1 & 0 & 1 & -2 &1/2 & 0 &0& 4 &  \\ \hline
s_2 & 0 & 0 & 5&-1& 1 &0& 0&  \\ \hline
s_3 & 0 & 0 & 9&7/2& 0 &1&57& \\ \hline
\end{array}

The next pivoting column will be $x_2$ with the $s_2$ row as the minimum ratio test produced by the $s_2$ row will be zero. Thus, watching for the minimum ratio test being the same value for multiple rows is where to detect degeneracy.

---

We could think of degeneracy like this: An extreme point occurs when
$n$ constraints overlap at a certain point, with where $n$ is denoted by the current dimension of $\Bbb R^n$. If another constraint overlaps an extreme point such that there are $n+1$ constraints on one point, then it can either do three things:

1. It exists on top of the another constraints,
2. It cuts off a part of the feasible region of the model,
3. It doesn’t do either 1) or 2) and exists in the model to only overlap one extreme point shared by the other $n$ constraints.

In part 1), it would obviously be redundant, as it would be a duplicate constraint. For part 2), that third constraint would make one of the another constraints redundant as it cuts off more of the feasible region than one of the other two constraints and is better than one of the other ones. For part 3), if a constraint only exists on one point in the model that $n$ other constraints already intersect/make an extreme point at, then it would redundant as it doesn’t contribute anything more to the model than what has already been contributed by those $n$ other constraints.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to detect degeneracy from constraints without solving the system perse? Some sources say it's from redundant contraints. Another says that it's indicated when a basic solution has one or more variable that takes on values of 0. But ideally I could validate constraints before solving anything, and get rid of redundant constraints? However, I am not entirely convinced degeneracy is due to "redundant" constraints as that source says.

Comment: You could investigate if a constraint is actually produced by the sum of the other constraints in model. Degeneracy occurs when more than two constraints overlap at the same point, and that would introduce redundancy as for each extreme point in a model really only needs two constraints to intersect it

Comment: I’ve re-edited my answer to include a response to your comment, as it was quite long

Comment: Well I don't think degeneracy happens when 2 vectors intersect perse, but maybe when 3 plus intersect (on all N dimensions?). It's a bit confusing.

Comment: You are correct, it would happen at a minimum three constraints intersect at the same extreme point, and yeah it’s kinda weird to wrap your head around

Comment: Ok, 3 constraints minimum, but those 3 vectors have N dimensions.. so also: intersecting in ALL N dimensions or just 2+ dimensions? I would guess all N dimensions. but dunno. comprende?

Comment: I've came back to this and I do believe now it may be possible to have degeneracy in just $\Bbb R$. Suppose we have three $x\ge3$ constraints and three $x\le7$ constraints. Then it would possible that the Simplex method is forced to make unnecessary pivots as it's going between both extreme points. I will think on this much more

Comment: Learning more on my side, I hear it's when there are X variables (X dimensions) and more than X constraints are active at a point.

Comment: Forget about this, but yeah I asked around and learnt more and that’s true! The issue with my initial understanding was thinking about how it works transcribing from $\Bbb R^2$ to most $\Bbb R^n$. I've updated my answer to include this. Thank you for this journey!!!

Comment: Thanks, so yeah I need to write some code to detect degeneracy in input data to a problem